# Firebase Firestore Permission denied: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to change the current Firebase project of my app but when I try to create a new user
(When creating a user with email and password it also creates a document in the firestore database) I get this error :

```
 Write at users/<user id> failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

I saw that it was caused because of the rule I set for the firestore but my rule is on true :
[firestore rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOKZe.png)

I tried looking for an answer but everybody always says that it is caused by the rule I have set

Comment: Please show us the code that you're using and throw that exception.

Comment: Yes, the reason of the issue must probably be the rules, please can you show the code of the rule you specified on FireStore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You will have to update the rules in the Firestore tab in Firebase**

Go to Firebase -> Firestore -> Rules

[Firestore rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIglh.png)

Then edit the rules like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how I've allowed anyone to read and write:
`allow read, write;`

And voila! You'll be able to write data in your Firestore now